# position vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

The line $L$ passes through a point with position vector $5\vec{k}$ and is parallel to the vector $a\vec{i}+b\vec{j}+c\vec{k}$ where $a$,$b$ and $c$  are positive integers. The shortest distance between $L$ and the line $r=u\vec{j}$ is 4 units where $h$ and $u$ are real numbers. find one possible set of values of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

the vector equation  for L is < 0 ,0, 5 > + t < a , b, c > = < 0,0,5> + t P; 
the point (0,u,0) is on the line r , let Q = < 0 , u , - 5 > be the vector that goes from r to L ; then [ P x Q x P ] is orthogonal to both L and r...using the dot product we have

4 | P x Q x P | = [ P x Q x P ] dot Q...this will yield relationships involving a , b , c